# How to convert UNIX timestamp into relative date like whatsapp last seen status with moment.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I would like to show a UNIX timestamp into last seen status same as what WhatsApp does in javascript. I am using `moment.js` and as far as I know, we can format the date or can use `.fromNow()` which gives a relative date but not what I am looking for.

For example,
Lets the Unix timestamp : 1606908420

If I use `moment.unix(1606908420).formNow()` the result will be  `few seconds ago` or something similar

But what I am looking for is, it should show `Today 11:30 am`.

Likewise

```
For a date of yesterday, it should show: Yesterday 11:30 am
For a date of day before yesterday, it should show: Mon 11:30 am

Any date of last week or earlier, it should show 25-11-2020
```

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't want a relative date at all. Check the age of the date and decide based on that which format to use

Comment: Okay, so basically I need to filter the date if today  yesterday, or any date of earlier based on that I set my tag line ?

Comment: Try using moment calendar like this: `moment.unix(UNIX_TIMESTAMP).calendar()`

Comment: @TabrezBasha, Yes its works like how i want ty :)

Answer (score 1):

*Convert Moment Date to looks like In Whatsapp*

```
//utility function to convert your date to looks like in whatsapp

const dateFormatter = (date) => {

    //here we were subtracting our date from current time which will be in milliseconds
    const dateDifferenceInTime =
        new Date().getTime() - new Date(date.toDate()).getTime();

    // conerting milli seconds to days
    // (1000 milliseconds * (60 seconds * 60 minutes) * 24 hours)
    const dateDifferenceInDays =
        dateDifferenceInTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    //After returning in particular formats as of our convinent
    if (dateDifferenceInDays < 1) {
        return moment(date.toDate()).format("LT");// 10:04 am
    } else if (dateDifferenceInDays < 2) {
        return "Yesterday"; // just YesterDay
    } else if (dateDifferenceInDays <= 7) {
        return moment(date.toDate()).format("dddd");//like monday , tuesday , wednesday ....
    } else {
        return moment(date.toDate()).format("l");// if it was more than a week before it will returns as like 05/23/2022
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Convert UNIX timestamp into date

1. using *toDate()* method

   `{new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}`

   `Wed, 2 Dec 2020 12:00:00 GMT`
2. using *moment* method

   `{moment.unix(order.data.created).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mma")}`

I highly recommend the second one *moment* for you. learn more from
[moment docs](https://momentjs.com/)